# Seeking alternatives to Business Analyst, AnySite/MapInfo, and Sites To Do Business?

Tags: arcmap, mapinfo, software-recommendations, spatial-analysis, business-analyst

This is a very general question and I hope it is ok. I've been "Googling" and can't find much. I work at a shop that currently uses MapInfo + [AnySite](http://www.empower.com/site_selection.htm) to do real estate site analysis. I generate demographic reports on US zip codes and by radii (usually 1, 2, and 3 miles).Se

The workflow is either:

1. Select zip codes -> run "hot spot" analysis (which is an automated
   z-score comparison within the software) and export table of data for
   selected zip codes (in a preformatted table).
2. Create point for site -> draw desired radii -> generate report based
   on these radii.

As AnySite and MapInfo cost us a hefty sum (even more than ArcGIS would), I'm tasked with finding an alternative. So far I have found ArcMap and Sites To Do Business (which I really hope we avoid).

Do you know of any others or of search terms I could use?

I'm stuck beyond the two I have already found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the kind of academic term you are referring to is "Site Selection".

Also, Anysite is a peculiar product, in that it includes a whole bunch of data as standard, which is why for many GIS Professionals it appears rather expensive for what it does, which in reality isn't all that difficult and only really undertakes fundamental analysis which most spatial software would be able to undertake quite easily.

The power (and therefore the theoretical justification for the cost) of Anysite comes with the **combination** of the data and the software (albeit quite poor software) ... not one or the other.

So if you are looking to procure something to replace you setup, ensure you have both the data and software components covered otherwise you may very well find the old adage "grass is always greener" rings true.

Also, if you're in Australia, the ABS table builder can provide you with much of the data that sits within AnySite, including links with geography IDs. It would take an inordinate amount of time to get it all as its obviously a massive amount of data, but if you had something small and tightly scoped you could use this to replicate the data and then use your GIS package of choice to do the analysis.

Comment: Regarding the data within Anysite. The Census data provided is "straight" Basic Community Profiles / Time Series and Indigenous Profiles. These can be purchased as stand alone DVDs (including the boundaries) from the ABS directly - with more information in them then provided via AnySite - the working age profile might be of interest for you -(http://abs.gov.au/websitedbs/censushome.nsf/home/datapacks?opendocument&navpos=250). Table Builder is an online product which enables manipulation and cross tabing of Census data (2006 and 2011) - so bespoke tables.

Comment: ... (ran out of space!). Unless your thinking of generating specialised cross tabs then I'd suggest only looking at the contents of the stand alone DVDs. Outside of that the other data provided in AnySite is population projections at a small area (I'm dubious of the methodology!) - many Planning Departments release this kind of thing on line (see http://data.nsw.gov.au/ for a NSW example).

Comment: Agree with Andrew, if you have the knowhow and time, get the Datapacks (cost a few hundred dollars) and use the Table Builder for specific tables. Thats the data covered.

Then use any GIS you wish! QGIS is open source and with expertise you could do anything Anysite could do with a little effort.

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually in the United States but you're right about the data and AnySite - it's kind of packaged with it (which is nice).

Do you know if ESRI's Business Analyst includes similar data?

Comment: Yes, I believe it does, how it is licensed and packaged together is another question though. As I said - Anysite has software and data packaged together, when you get on the phone with your ESRI account manager ensure you're comparing apples to apples.

If you still want to do it on the really cheap I would be suprised if there wasn't an equivalent to the Australia ABS DataPack from the US Census Bureau. You guys have a really good interactive online tool "American FactFinder" - http://tinyurl.com/3rf9lf8 which has quite advanced data download and interaction capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend Maptitude as a geospatial software package to meet your spatial analysis needs.  I have been a user of the software for about 3 years now, as the software is quite affordable compared to MapInfo and ESRI Business Analyst Online.  The software is aimed at the business/real estate person who needs to do site selection work, hot spots, demographic analysis, and advanced trade area analysis.  The software is easy to use, customizable, and can easily bring in point data from an Excel Spreadsheet with your store attribute data including latitude/longitude or by address (the software comes with a great geocoder).  You can also build your own formulas to do a custom analysis.  Included with your country package of choice is detailed census data available at the county, zip code and census tract levels.

Maptitude - http://www.caliper.com/maptovu.htm
Map Examples - http://www.cardgeog.com/business/analyzing-new-locations/

Answer (score 2):

To do real estate site analysis inexpensively, I'd recommend Meridian Econometrics' tool at www.meridianecon.com. It's very easy to use, and the visualizations and reports are clean and useful. The maps use contours instead of choropleth to differentiate zones according to search criteria, and the analytical engine incorporates mobility. All in all it's a lot of help for very little money.